# How to reference a file (e.g. testaudio.mp3) from another file (e.g. index.html) in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I have a **mp3 file** in a folder called "audio" in Alfresco. I would like to have a link that points to that file in my **index.html** file which resides in another folder.

For example: `<a href="pathToTheFile>test song 1</a>`

How would I reference that file? I tried with `href="/share/proxy/alfresco/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/xxx-xxx-xxxxx/testMP3.mp3"` and it does not work. Or is it even possible with Alfresco? I am using the web interface.

---

My apologies for not making myself clear. I am using **Alfresco Explorer Community Edition** for management, and the website I'm working on is based on Spring MVC and pulls content from `index.html` files in Alfresco.

Currently I need to use `<embed>` tags to include a **mp3 file** to `index.html`, and the mp3 file is also stored within the Alfresco repository but in a different folder.

How would I reference the mp3 file from the `index.html` file? The referencing has to work when the `index.html` is deployed to the client website, and currently the client website is referencing files in Alfresco in the following manner: `<img src=/asset/xxxxxx-xx-xxx/test.png>`(There is no `asset` folder in the Alfresco repository, and somehow that works...). But this does not work for my mp3 file...

Comment: How are you intending to view the referencing HTML file? Web QuickStart? Share? Other?

Comment: @Gagravarr Hey thanks for the comment, I've updated my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access alfresco content using the RESTful api, you should be querying this webscript: `/alfresco/d/<d|a>/<workspace>/<store>/<nodeId>/<filename>` 
where :

- `d` and `a` refer to direct / attached mode
- `<workspace>`, `<store>` and `<nodeId>` reference your content nodeRef
- `<filename>` a file name of your choice

So your URL should look something like this `http://<host>:<port>/alfresco/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/8444ad61-4734-40e3-b2d4-b8b1c81347fd/test.mp3`

**Note :** Depending on the permission set on your node, you might need to attach an alf_ticket to the URL for an authenticated alfresco user. Please check [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/tasks/ws-specify-user-identity.html) for further insights.

Comment: Thanks buddy that was helpful, can you please help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782485/no-collections-folder-when-creating-a-folder-in-alfresco) question as well? Basically I don't have the `collections` folder and I need it