# No collections folder when creating a folder in Alfresco

Tags: audio, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have created a folder called `audio_test` under `root` folder in Alfresco using the Alfresco Share client, but there is only the `index.html` file but no `collections` folder.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/qs-understand-content.html) I need the `collections` folder to manage my audio files so that my web app can access them. Why isn't there a `collections` folder for me? Or how do I create one myself?

Comment: I am not familiar with alfresco-wqs, do you mind explaining what are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Normally WebQuickStart works on specific sites of the WQS type. Putting files in the root of the Alfresco repo sounds wrong to me. What happens if you create a WQS site and then create the file in the doclib of that?

Comment: @YReg im trying to use the collections folder to manage some of my audio files. But the system won't create one for me.

Comment: @Gagravarr The root folder I refer to here is the root folder of the site I created, which is under documentLibrary :)

Comment: @Gagravarr The root folder I refer to here is the root folder of the site I created, which is under documentLibrary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps described in the following pages:

[Creating the Web Quick Start site](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/WQS-create-site.html)

to create the WQS. Each root folder in WQS has a folder where you can define your collections. Collections can be static or dynamic (based on a cmis query).

You need to create this WQS site, upload your files and then define your collections.